# ElasticSearch errors in deleting records by query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to delete large-number of documents in ES via delete_by_query.
But I am seeing the following errors.

Query

```
POST indexName/typeName/_delete_by_query
{ 
  "size": 100000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { 
          "range": {
            "CREATED_TIME": {
              "gte": 0,
              "lte": 1507316563000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  } 
}
```

Result

```
{
  "took": 50489,
  "timed_out": false,
  "total": 100000,
  "deleted": 0,
  "batches": 1,
  "version_conflicts": 1000,
  "noops": 0,
  "retries": {
    "bulk": 0,
    "search": 0
  },
  "throttled_millis": 0,
  "requests_per_second": -1,
  "throttled_until_millis": 0,
  "failures": [
    {
      "index": "indexName",
      "type": "typeName",
      "id": "HVBLdzwnImXdVbq",
      "cause": {
        "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
        "reason": "[typeName][HVBLdzwnImXdVbq]: version conflict, current version [2] is different than the one provided [1]",
        "index_uuid": "YPJcVQZqQKqnuhbC9R7qHA",
        "shard": "1",
        "index": "indexName"
      },
      "status": 409
    },....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [this article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html).

You have two ways of handling this issue, by set the *url* to ignore version conflicts or set the *query* to ignore version conflicts:

> If you’d like to count version conflicts rather than cause them to abort then set `conflicts=proceed` on the url or `"conflicts": "proceed"` in the request body.